How can I use `declare_program!` for client side rust?
Anchor 0.30.0 added the declare_program! macro which generates rust bindings from an anchor idl. I was able to find examples on how to use this for CPIs, but not for how to do this for client-side rust similar to how it works with typescript. If I have an instruction called MyInstruction as part of my_program, I can do:
use anchor_lang::prelude::*;
declare_program!(my_program);
use my_program::client::accounts::MyInstruction as MyInstructionAccs;
use my_program::client::args::MyInstruction as MyInstructionArgs;

let accs = MyInstructionAccs {
    acc1: someAccount,
};
let args = MyInstructionArgs { 
    arg1: someArg,
};


Is there anything else Anchor can do for me from here to actually build & send this transaction and invoke MyInstruction in my_program?
Edit: I'm not asking how to generate a client program for Rust in general, as there's already a number of tools for this. Judging from this issue the idea behind declare_program! was to remove the need for external crates to do this, which is why I'm asking.

I think you might be looking for the Anchor Client library:
https://docs.rs/anchor-client/latest/anchor_client/
It allows you, through the program call loaded as a Rust program dependency, to directly access the Account state and invoke instructions.
For example, to get account data for the Marinade staking program, I did the following:
https://github.com/ochaloup/marinade-anchor-client/blob/main/src/main.rs
For transaction invocation, you can use request(), passing in the accounts and the instruction data. This isn't a full example, but you can check the direction we take here:
https://github.com/marinade-finance/marinade-common-rs-cli/blob/main/libs/marinade-client-rs/src/marinade/instructions.rs#L23
The Program ID is generated into the Rust code after the macros are expanded (anchor expand) and then used directly within the client-side program with use marinade_finance::ID;.

This is a helpful answer in general, but I won't accept it because I was asking for how to do this with declare_program!. This might've not been 100% clear from my question before I edited it though, so I'll still upvote this :)

Oh, I see the point now, I have not got the point sorry. While not having the 0.30.0 experience ‍♂️

Upon further consideration I realize I misunderstood what declare_program! was for and your answer is the best way to do things so I accepted it. This raised other problems: https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/14296/how-do-i-use-declare-program-with-anchor-client , but that's a separate story. Thank you for your answer!
