How do I build a transaction using `declare_program!` with anchor_client?
If I try to create a transaction using declare_program! for accounts and args and anchor_client for building the transaction:
use anchor_lang::prelude::*;
declare_program!(my_program);
use my_program::client::accounts::MyInstruction as MyInstructionAccs;
use my_program::client::args::MyInstruction as MyInstructionArgs;
use anchor_client::Program;
use anchor_lang::prelude::*;
use solana_sdk::signer::Signer;


pub fn send_startup_tx<C: Deref<Target = impl Signer> + Clone>(
    p: Program<C>,
    acc: Pubkey,
    param: u32,
) {
    let accs = MyInstructionAccs {
        acc1: acc,
    };
    let args = MyInstructionArgs { 
        arg1: param,
    };
    let a = p.request().accounts(accs).args(args)
}

This unfortunately doesn't build, with the following error
the trait bound `__client_accounts_my_instruction::MyInstruction: anchor_client::anchor_lang::ToAccountMetas` is not satisfied

If I do cargo expand, I can also see why: declare_program! generates an impl for anchor_lang::ToAccountMetas, but not for anchor_client::anchor_lang::ToAccountMetas even though these two are the exact same in practice.
I've tried switching my import at the top to use anchor_client::anchor_lang::declare_program; but it still gives the same error. Any idea on how to fix this?

Turns out I was just using two different versions of anchor_client and anchor_lang. Made sure both are the same version, and it works perfectly now.
